# Twitter Tweet Widget not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Kindly take a look at the following code. Is there something wrong with it my twitter widget is not working anymore but its was few days earlier from the very same code/ Kindly help thanks,

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 216,
  height: 240,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#292b2c'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#f6f6f6',
      color: '#292b2c',
      links: '#1388d2'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('ganasal').start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the widget's code:
"The Twitter API v1.0 is deprecated, and this widget has ceased functioning. You can replace it with a new, upgraded widget..."